# Epsilon-delta for $\lim_{x\to 0} 7e^{\frac x{(1-x)}}+1=8$

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

> $$\lim_{x\to 0} 7e^{\dfrac x{(1-x)}}+1=8$$

I am trying to write epsilon-delta proof but I am stuck 
what i've got is:

$|e^{x/(1-x)}-1|< ε/7$

so my goal is to make it look like $|x|< δε$

I know that I can evaluate $|e^{x/(1-x)}-1|$ using remarkable limit and obtain:
 $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(e^{x/(1-x)}-1) (x/(1-x))}{x/(1-x)}= 0,$$

but I have no idea how to proceed further

any hints?

Comment: Please see this tutorial on MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What is $E$? Was it a typo?

Comment: @Teddy38 It is Epsilon. Now edited. Thanks

Comment: The point of this exercise must be that one should **never** do the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof directly for such limit. On the other hand, you could prove using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ language that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{1-x}=0$ and then prove that the exponential function is continuous, which depends on its definition!

Comment: @Jack, Got it. Thank you.

Comment: In other words, the function is defined and continuous at x=0